# Fetch a specific user timeline from Twitter

Tags: twitter

I'm building an application that should listen to a specific user timeline, can I use the API for that or is the API more of a "I want to build my own Twitter client" thingy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have authenticated using OAuth (the real hard part) you can pull tweets from a timeline from a Http Get `http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?user_id=12345`

Documentation here;
http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/user_timeline

If your next question is "So how do I do OAuth" you can grab [some code to do it](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/OAuth-Examples).